# Can CLI archives be deployed on WildFly using Maven plugin?

Tags: maven, plugins, command-line-interface, wildfly, archive

How do I a deploy CLI archive (zipped) in WildFly (8-10) *using wildfly-maven-plugin?*

I've created a [simple example](https://filebin.redpill-linpro.com/bckgu06s74boujjz): A Maven project with a archive.cli file. This archive will deploy a PostgreSQL jdbc driver.

If I deploy it using jboss-cli.sh/bat, it works just as expected: The PostgreSQL driver will appear as an deployment.

Try:

> deploy src/main/archive.cli

If I deploy it using maven-wildfly-plugin, WildFly will deploy the file but won't unzip/expand it - I've have a useless archive.cli file as a deployment, but no driver installed. Why?

Try:

> mvn validate

My pom.xml looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">

    <name>deploy-archive-cli</name>
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.foo</groupId>
    <artifactId>deploy-archive-cli</artifactId>
    <version>1</version>
    <packaging>pom</packaging>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.2.1.Final</version> 
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>deploy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <filename>archive.cli</filename>
                            <targetDir>src/main/</targetDir>
                            <skip>false</skip>
                            <checkPackaging>false</checkPackaging>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>                
                </executions>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
</project>
```

Project strukture looks like this:

```
.
├── pom.xml
└── src
    └── main
        ├── archive
        │   ├── deploy.scr
        │   ├── postgresql-42.2.1.jar
        │   └── undeploy.scr
        └── archive.cli
```

Java8. I've tried using deploy-artifact, Win/Linux, WildFly 8-10... Can I configure wildfly-maven-plugin and tell it to expand the artifact? An example would be appreciated.

I understand alternatives are to deploy EAR/WAR/JAR artifacts using Maven, or running jboss-cli, but this is how one IT department would like to handle it. It should be possible, huh?

The simple example Maven project can be downloaded [here](https://filebin.redpill-linpro.com/bckgu06s74boujjz)

thanks,

Jens

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that CLI deployments are part of CLI and not processed by normal deployment operations. However in the maven plugin you can execute CLI commands.

For your example the pom configuration would look something like the following.

```xml
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.1.Final</version> 
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>validate</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>execute-commands</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <commands>
                    <command>deploy --path=${project.basedir}/src/main/archive.cli</command> 
                </commands>
            </configuration>
        </execution>                
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

One thing to note is while testing this I discovered [WFMP-94](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFMP-94). If you're using Java 1.8.0_161 you may run into this error. It worked fine for me on the Oracle JDK 1.8.0_151 however.

Comment: Awesome, workaround works like a charm! Thanks a bunch.

Comment: But...this was actually a simplification of issues I got when trying to deploy an cli-file directly from a Maven repository (using wildfly:deploy-artifact). 

And since the CLI cannot deploy from a Maven repository and maven-wildfly-plugin obviously cannot deploy cli-files... It there an workaround for that too?

Comment: I'm not sure if there is a workaround for that. I suppose you could use the `maven-dependency-plugin` to copy the artifact to your target directory and then execute the CLI deploy command.